# How can i wrap a span around each letter

Tags: jquery

I have tried but failed to wrap each number in its owns span>a

example html

```
<div class="ls_team_points">10.1</div>
<div class="ls_team_points">9.4</div>
<div class="ls_team_points">0</div>
<div class="ls_team_points">17</div>
```

I want final html to look like this

```
<div class="ls_team_points"><span><a>1</a></span><span><a>0</a></span><span><a>.</a></span><span><a>1</a></span></div>
<div class="ls_team_points"><span><a>9</a></span><span><a>.</a></span><span><a>4</a></span></div>
<div class="ls_team_points"><span><a>0</a></span></div>
<div class="ls_team_points"><span><a>1</a></span><span><a>7</a></span></div>
```

I tried this but no idea how to get it working properly

```
$('.ls_team_points').html(function (i, html) {
    var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
    return '<span><a>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</a></span>';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need close and reopen the tag "a" on join()

```js
$('.ls_team_points').html(function (i, html) {
    var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
    return '<span><a>' + chars.join('</a></span><span><a>') + '</a></span>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('.ls_team_points').each(function(){
  $(this).html(function (i, html) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i=0; i < html.length; i++) {
       str += '<span><a>' + html.charAt(i) + '</a></span>';
    }
    return str;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ls_team_points">10.1</div>
<div class="ls_team_points">9.4</div>
<div class="ls_team_points">0</div>
<div class="ls_team_points">17</div>
```